# Add number to each element in a list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to add a number to each element in a list and the sublists.The list also contains a tree(The functor cannot be numeric only leaves can be numeric).

```
% Checking if element in a list is a tree
istree(H) :- istree(_,F).
istree(_,F) :- isforest(F).
isforest([]).
isforest([T|Ts]) :- istree(T), isforest(Ts).
```

When I try running the query it fails.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a typo in the clause `istree(H) :- istree(_,F).`. You Prolog system likely printed a warning about singleton variables in that clause.

Comment: I tested that piece of code and it works fine.It shows true if a given term is a multiway tree.Can you tell me where else I might be going wrong.

Comment: Of course it shows true! You're calling the `istree/2` predicate with a variable in the second argument, which means calling the `isforest/1` with a variable argument.

Comment: Is there any other way to check if a given element is a tree in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement is

> I am trying to add a number to each element in a list and the sublists.
>   The list also contains a tree (The functor cannot be numeric only leaves can be numeric).

You don't say *how* your "trees" are represented. However, this is a pretty simple traversal problem. You can do something pretty generic, like this, that will accept any arbitrary prolog term and increment all numbers found within:

```
increment( X , Y , Z ) :- number(X)   , ! , Z is X+Y ) .
increment( X , Y , Z ) :- var(X)      , ! , Z = X .
increment( X , Y , Z ) :- atomic(X)   , ! . Z = X . % atomic terms, including the empty list, remain unchanged.
increment( X , Y , Z ) :- compound(X) , ! ,         % otherwise, we have a compound term, including a non-empty list...
  X =.. [Functor|Args] ,                            % - decompose the compound term into its functor and argument list
  increment(Args,Y,Args1) ,                         % - increment the argument list
  Z =.. [Functor|Args1] ,                           % - assemble the new, incremented compound term
  .                                                 % Easy!
```

You don't really need explicity tests for lists as the empty list is just the atom `'[]'` and a non-empty list `[Head|Tail]` is merely syntactic sugar for the prolog term `'.'(Head,Tail)`, with the convention being that `Tail` is either the empty list (`[]`) or another non-empty list.

However, you might *want* explicit test for lists as I suspect many (most?) prologs have special list implementations so as to improve performance.

If you wanted to restrict your `increment/3` to just lists, you could do something like this, where `increment/3` traverses a list and applies a transform to each element found within:

```
increment( []     , _ , []     ) :-
increment( [X|Xs] , Y , [Z|Zs] ) :-
  transform( X  ,Y , Z  ) ,
  increment( Xs ,Y , Zs )
  .

transform(X,Y,Z) :- var(X)      , ! , Z = X .
transform(X,Y,Z) :- number(X)   , ! , Z is X+Y .
transform(X,Y,Z) :- is_list(X)  , ! , increment(X,Y,Z) .
transform(X,Y,Z) :- atomic(X)   , ! , Z = Z .
transform(X,Y,Z) :- compound(X) , ! ,
  X =.. [F|As] ,       % - decompose the compound term into its functor and list of arguments
  increment(As,Y,A1) , % - increment the argument list
  Z =.. [F|A1]         % - assemble the incremented compount term
  .                    % Easy!
```

`is_list/1` is a built-in predicate for SWI Prolog. If your prolog doesn't have one, it's trivial to roll your own. Here are two implementations.

This is an exhaustive test for listness. It validates the entire recursive definition of a list: a list is either the atom `[]` or a non-empty list `[H|T]` where `T` is itself a list. This is the implementation used by SWI Prolog:

```
is_list(  X    ) :- var(X) , ! , fail . % variables are not lists
is_list(  []   ) .                      % the empty list
is_list( [_|T] ) :- is_list(T) .        % a non-empty list has a tail that is itself a list
```

One should note that for long lists, this might be a somewhat expensive operation since it requires traversing the entire list. To that end, you might want to use a simpler test that only looks at the topmost term:

```
is_list(  X     ) :- var(X) , ! , fail . % variables are not lists
is_list(  []    ) .                      % the empty list
is_list(  [_|_] ) .                      % a non-empty list
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of mutual recursion between `istree/1` and `isforest/1`. If you want to enforce the property you probably want code like this:

```
istree([]).
istree([H|T]) :- 
   (number(H) ; istree(H)), 
   istree(T).
```

No mutual recursion here though.

Your `istree/1`/`istree/2` code is pretty wide of the mark. I wouldn't worry so much about these two clauses except you indicated to @PauloMoura that you think that code "works fine" when in reality it will do basically nothing. It will accept anything without producing any bindings. Error messages from Prolog about singleton variables should be taken as *dire, critical errors* which *must* be addressed. Try and follow the logic through with your `istree/1` predicate. There's no relationship between `H` and `F`. Prolog will say `yes` because `istree(_,F)` succeeds by calling `isforest(F)` and then binding `F = []`, but this is thrown away back in `istree/1` because there is no relationship between `H` and `F`. Think it through. There's no way it "works fine"—it doesn't do anything at all. You could replace it with `true`.

Your `isforest/1` looks pretty good, it's just assuming that there's a legitimate `istree/1` to call. If I wanted to fit in with the mutual recursion theme, I might try this:

```
istree(E) :- number(E).
istree([H|T]) :- isforest([H|T]).
```

None of this gets you very close to adding a number to each element of a list and the sublists, which you mention is your task. I assume you mean that arithmetically, so for instance `addToTree([1,[2],3], 3, [4,[5],6])` would unify. To do that I'd do this:

```
% base case: empty list
addToTree([], _, []).

% case 1: head is a number
addToTree([H|T], N, [HN|Rest]) :- 
  number(H),
  HN is H+N, 
  addToTree(T, N, Rest).

% case 2: head is a list
addToTree([H|T], N, [NH|Rest]) :- 
  is_list(H), 
  addToTree(H, N, NH), 
  addToTree(T, N, Rest).
```